# How can I notify property of parents that property of child is changed

Tags: c#

I have the following code, I would like to have a way where changes in `p1` are visible in access direct or propertygrid.
thank you for your help

```
public class A
{
    int _c = 0;

    public int p1 //this is child property
    {
        get { return _c; }
        set { _c = value; } //here change, notify class B that p1 is changed
    }

}

public class B
{
    A _a = new A();

    public A p2  //this is parents property
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not edit your question to change it into a completely new one! Post a new question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET has a interface built in that does this for you, [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

What you do is you have the setter raise the event and then the parent subscribes to the event.

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _c = 0;

    public int p1 //this is child property
    {
        get { return _c; }
        set 
        {
            if(_c != value)
            {
                 OnNotifyPropertyChanged("p1");
                 _c = value;
            } 
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       var tmp = PropertyChanged;
       if (tmp != null)
       {
          tmp (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
    }
}

public class B
{
    Public B()
    {
       _a = new A();
       _a.PropertyChanged += AChanged;
    }

    A _a;

    private AChanged(object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "p1")
        {
            //do your work here on change
        }
    }

    public A p2  //this is parents property
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set 
        {
           if(Object.ReferenceEquals(_a, value) == false)
           {
              _a.PropertyChanged -= AChanged; //unsubcribe from the old event
              value.PropertyChanged += AChanged; //subscribe to the new event
           }
           _a = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but i have a question if I clone Class B and PropertyChaged is assigned. doesn't it have problem?

Comment: Ah that was an interesting case @ScottChamberlain. I removed my answer. Don't think it helps much.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to know this is not parent child relation it is composition. if you want inheritence i will show you how you can achieve your goal through following code.

```
public class A:B
{
    int _c = 0;

    public int p1 //this is child property
    {
        get { return _c; }
        set { _c = value; isChiledchanged= true; } //here change, notify class B that p1 is changed
    }

}

public class B
{
   public bool isChildchanged = false;


}
```