# Update value of parent instance in nested listing

Tags: c#, wpf

This may be trivial.  But I could not able to get my heads over this.

```
public class Manager
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllEmpEngaged { get; set; }
    public void UpdateIsAllEmpEngaged()
    {
        IsAllEmpEngaged = Employees.All(emp => emp.IsEngagedwithWork == true);
    }

}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsEngagedwithWork { get; set; }
}
```

So, Whenever, the `IsEngagedwithWork` of `Employee` is setted with some value, I want to check whether all the `Employees` under a`Manager` is Engaged with work or not and update the value of `IsAllEmpEngaged` of the respective `Manager`.

***I just want to call `UpdateIsAllEmpEngaged` on changes in property `IsEngagedwithWork` of `Employee`. How can I achieve this?***

Any other ways are also welcome.

**Note:** I tried with a having an `event` on `Employee` and attach `Action` from the `Manager` that will callback if any changes in `Employee` property.  But I will be having hundreds of `List<Manager>`.  I dont want to add event for each and every instance of `Employee` class.  Any easy way?

### **Update:**

I am working with WPF MVVM approach,  I cannot use direct `get with LinQ` as it will not notify the UI.  I have to `set` the property manually for change so that it will `Notify` the UI.

Also,  In actual case, the IsEngagedwithWork will be updated in UI for the property `IsEngagedwithWork`.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged should be the way to go. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849622/how-can-i-notify-property-of-parents-that-property-of-child-is-changed

Comment: Have you tried to pass the parent manager via constructor to employee class ?

Comment: Do you need to this happen automatically? What will you do with IsAllEmpEngaged property then? If you will still poll it, then I would say make a method for checking if AllEmployees are engaged by empowering linq expression on Employees. 

Employees.Any(e=>!e.IsEngagedWithWork); would return true only when all of them are engaged

Comment: You don't want to use this `manager.Employees.Any(x => x.IsEngagedwithWork )` ?

Comment: You could keep reference to parent `Manager` in `Employee` and updated it any time employee is changed.

Comment: @Joh.  I haven.t tried.  Will try and let you know.

Comment: @MichaelMao I can use.  But the problem is I would I call the method?  See my updates on `Manager` class

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks.  I will give a try on that.  Will it load more? because I have to keep the reference for all the `employee` (say 100 emp) for each `Manager`

Comment: @Joh.  Will it load more? because I have to keep the reference for all the `employee` (say 100 emp) for each `Manager`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is add **ManagerId** as well to the Employee model class and after your line of code that sets IsEngagedwithWork of the employee instance (say emp), do the below thing

`Manager mngr = managers.Select(m => m.ID == emp.ManagerId).FirstOrDefault();`

`if(mngr != null)`
 `mngr.IsAllEmpEngaged = mngr.IsAllEmpEngaged && emp.IsEngagedwithWork;`

Comment: If I'm not wrong `mngr.IsAllEmpEngaged = mngr.IsAllEmpEngaged && emp.IsEngagedwithWork;` should not be in `Employee` class as thats not the responsibility of the `Employee` calss to update stuffs in `Manager`

Comment: Yes. I believed the IsEngagedwithWork setter you were calling from somewhere else and not from inside the Employee class. So following that line of code that you have, which may be like `emp.IsEngagedwithWork = true;` I suggested to add rest of the lines in my answer.

Comment: Okay.  In actual case, the `IsEngagedwithWork` will be updated in UI and it will be notified to the Setter of the property.  Hope I'm clear

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the getter of the property like that

```
 public bool IsAllEmpEngaged { 
   get {
       return (Employees != null) && 
                   Employees.All(e => e.IsEngagedwithWork)
   }
}
```

and you add the following method for the Manager Class

```
 public void NotifyChanged() { OnPropertyChanged(() => IsAllEmpEngaged }
```

then you call it from the Employee Class (assuming you have the managers' list or an equivalent way)

```
private int _ID;
private bool _IsEngagedwithWork;
public int ID { 
     get { return _ID}; 
     set {
       _ID = value;
       OnPropertyChanged(()=>ID );
       notifyMe = managerList.FirstOrDefualt(m => m.ID == _ID);
       if (notifyMe != null) { notifyMe.NotifyChanged()}
     } 
}
public bool IsEngagedwithWork { 
       get { return _IsEngagedwithWork ;} 
       set {
             _IsEngagedwithWork = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(()=>IsEngagedwithWork );
             notifyMe = managerList.FirstOrDefualt(m => m.ID == _ID);
             if (notifyMe != null) { notifyMe.NotifyChanged()}
       }
```

}

Comment: Thanks.  But Im in need of `Set` the rpoerty so that I can notify the UI.  See the update in question

Comment: Besides your specific implementation choices/details, my message is that you don't need a setter to notify the UI, it's enough to call a notifier method... and consider that keeping only the getter is a more functional/robust approach, since it is a computed value and a setter there is misleading...

Answer (score 0):

What i would do :

- make IsAllEmpEngaged private
- make the collection Empoyess private and add a function that add a new employee:
- Add a function that adds a new employee.

And now two choiches :

1) after the employee is added, iterate the collection and update the IsAllEmpEngaged  property

```
 public void AddNewEmployee(Employee employee){
    this.Employees.Add(employee);           
    bool all = true;

    foreach(Employee emp in this.Employees){
        if (!emp.IsEngagedwithWork){
            all = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    this.IsAllEmpEngaged = all;          
}
```

2)

- start with IsAllEmpEngaged = true; when the class is inited and the  collection is empty
- when the employee is added, update the IsAllEmpEngaged  property but keeping count of the last choice (this works only if you don't remove employess)

  ```
  public void AddNewEmployee(Employee employee){
      this.Employees.Add(employee);           

      this.IsAllEmpEngaged = this.IsAllEmpEngaged && employee.IsEngagedwithWork 
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is any better, but surely this is a simple and easy way.

Why not just make `IsAllEmpEngaged` a method? You don't even need the `set` property accessor, so a method should suffice.

```
public bool IsAllEmpEngaged()
{
    if (Employees == null)
    {
        // throw error
    }

    return Employees.All(e => e.IsEngagedwithWork);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But Im in need of Set the property so that I can notify the UI. See the update in question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it work's when you pass your Manager as parameter to Employee and then call your Method if IsEngagedWithWork is set to true.

```
public class Employee
{
    private Manager _parentManager;

    public Employee(Manager parentManager)
    {
        _parentManager=parentManager;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    private bool _isEngangedWithWork;

    public bool IsEngagedwithWork
    { 
       get{ return _isEngangedWithWork; } 
       set
          {
             _isEngangedWithWork=value;
             if(_isEngangedWithWork)
              _parentManager.UpdateIsAllEmpEngaged();
           }
    }
}
```